# jQuery Counter: Stop type when reach limit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a counter for text area and for now I success to count the length, but I want after it reach the limit, user can't type anymore.

How to make it stop able to type when reach the limit?

```
$('textarea').keyup(function () {
  var max = 10;
  var len = $(this).val().length;
  var char = max - len;
  if (len >= max) {
    $(this).parent().find('.counter').text(char + '/'+max);
    $(this).parent().find('.counter').css({"color":"red"});
  } 
  else {
    $(this).parent().find('.counter').text(char + '/'+max);
    $(this).parent().find('.counter').css({"color":"#ccc"});    
  }
});
```

heres the jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/5vf8pce3/

Comment: Use can also use maxlength attribute to prevent typing <textarea rows="1" cols="10" maxlength="10"></textarea>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1) change `keyup` to `keydown` and `return false;`. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/5vf8pce3/4/

2) or use [`maxlength` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) (HTML5).

```
<textarea maxlength="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: Checked the fiddle? It was working, but I edit now with backspace handling.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var maxLength = 10;
$('textarea').keyup(function() {
  var length = $(this).val().length;
  var length = maxLength-length;
  $(this).parent().find('.counter').text(length +"/"+maxLength);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control"  maxlength="10" rows="3"></textarea>
<span class="counter"></span>
```

Comment: its work sir, but the when reach the limit we still can type and change the last alphabet. how to disable the last alphabet. i mean when reach the limit, user really cant type anymore. great code btw

Comment: and its seems my other textarea get error counter, heres jsfiddle with your code https://jsfiddle.net/5vf8pce3/3/

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery handler can take an object. What I mean is the function that handles the keyup event can take an object which contains the event. The event then can be cancelled with the function preventDefault(). Fixed code:

```
$('textarea').keyup(function (event) {
  var max = 10;
  var len = $(this).val().length;
  var char = max - len;
  if (len >= max) {
    $(this).parent().find('.counter').text(char + '/'+max);
    $(this).parent().find('.counter').css({"color":"red"});
    event.preventDefault();
  } 
  else {
    $(this).parent().find('.counter').text(char + '/'+max);
    $(this).parent().find('.counter').css({"color":"#ccc"});    
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one..

```
$('textarea').keyup(function () {
var max = 10;
var len = $(this).val().length;
 var char = max - len;
if (len >= max) {

$(this).parent().find('.counter').text(char + '/'+max);
$(this).parent().find('.counter').css({"color":"red"});
$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
} 
else {
   $(this).parent().find('.counter').text(char + '/'+max);
  $(this).parent().find('.counter').css({"color":"#ccc"});    
 }
});
```